# How to compare an input string with an enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have my below enum -

```
public enum TestEnum {
    h1, h2, h3, h4;

    public static String forCode(int code) {
    return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestEnum.h1.name());
        String ss = "h1";

        // check here whether ss is in my enum or not

    }
}
```

Now what I want to check is given a String `h1`, I need to see whether this String `h1` is in my enum or not? How would I do this using the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest approach:

```
try {
   TestEnum.valueOf(ss); 
   System.out.println("valid");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   System.out.println("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use if statement check instead of this?

Comment: Not...not really, not without just shifting the work elsewhere.  You could build a static final map of the enum names, or loop directly over the enum values.

Comment: @SSH `values` and `valueOf` are defined by the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), and they didn't define a `boolean` version that checks.  It would have been a useful feature, I think.  (I don't know Java 8 yet--they didn't add this, did they?)  Anyway, if I didn't want to use exceptions I'd loop over `values`.

Comment: Thanks.. One more thing I just found out that, I need to compare `string ss` only with `h1` , `h2` or `h3` only in the enum.. I won't need to check with `h4` in the enum.. Any idea how do I do this with Enum in your current example?

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using `ordinals` for your `enum`. Rather give a value to each enum constant, and have a field.

So, your `enum` should look like:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    h1("h1"), h2("h2"), h3("h3"), h4("h4");

    private final String value;

    TestEnum(String value) { this.value = value; }

    public static TestEnum forValue(String value) {
        // You can cache the array returned by `values()` in the enum itself
        // Or build a map from `String` to `TestEnum` and use that here
        for (TestEnum val: values()) {
            if (val.value.equals(value)) {
                return val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then for a given String, you can check if it's valid value or not like this:

```
String value = "h1";

TestEnum enumValue = TestEnum.forValue(value);

if (enumValue == null) {
    System.out.println("Invalid value");
}
```

Comment: Maybe just use the `val.toString()` instead of adding the String as private Value. So there is no double addeting

Comment: @BennX That is an option, but I just wanted to show how to avoid using ordinals.

Comment: sure just wanted to mention. I use your solution to save different states at an enum. But in this case the doublewriting is not necessary but meight be usefull.

Comment: @BennX Yeah in this case it's not required, as OP is simply using the value same as the constant name.

Answer (score 1):

Setting values for each enum seemed unnecessary to me.  Here's a solution that uses toString() instead of .value, which I feel is a bit simpler:

```
public class tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestEnum enumValue = TestEnum.forValue("X1");
    if (enumValue == null) {
        System.out.println("Invalid value");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Good  value");
    }
}

public enum TestEnum {
    X1, X2, X#;

    public static TestEnum forValue(String value) {
        for (TestEnum val : values())
            if (val.toString().equals(value))
                return val;
        return null;
    }
}
```